# Radius of curvature for the plane curve $x^3 + y^3 = 12xy$.

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, curvature

Could someone help me with this problem? : Determine the radius of curvature for the plane curve $x^3 + y^3 = 12xy$ at the point $(0, 0)$.

Comment: Should I transform the equation into this: y = (12xy - x^3)/y^2 and then use this formula: http://www.math24.net/images/13sodi8.gif ?

Comment: No, that still contains y on the right hand side. Check out the discussion of curvature here for a formula and discussion: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27967/curvature-of-planar-implicit-curves

Comment: Notice also that (0,0) is a  point of the self intersection . (Look up Folium of Descartes or sketch the curve to see this. ) Link: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FoliumofDescartes.html

Answer (score 1):

Sketch: make the orthogonal change of coordinates $x+y=\sqrt{2}u,$ $x-y=\sqrt{2}v,$ then you can solve  $v=\pm f(u)$, where $f(u)$ is some smooth function  around $u=0$, $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)\neq 0$. So our curve has a self-intersection  at the origin, with each "branch" having the same curvature at the origin. Now take Taylor series at $u=0$, get $v=\pm(Au+Bu^2+...)$, which reduces to finding the curvature at the origin of the parabola $v=Au+Bu^2.$

Comment: I'm new to differential geometry and didn't understand too much of your answer. If you have time, would you mind giving me the entire solution? If the curve's equation were a bit different it would have been much easier for me to solve...

Comment: Sorry, I do not know what you know, so it is hard to know what you mean by "entire" solution. This forum has its limitations...

Answer (score 0):

The given curve is tangential to both the coordinate axes at the origin. So we can use Newton's formula. At the point of the curve where it is tangential to $x$-axis, the radius of curvature is

$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{x^2}{2y}.$

Divide $x^3+y^3=12xy$ by $2xy$ and take limits as $x$ tends to zero. Since both $y$ and $y/x$ tend to zero as $x$ tends to zero we get $\rho=6$ as the radius of curvature at the origin where the curve is tangential to $x$-axis. At the origin when the curve is tangential to the $y$-axis, interchange the roles of $x$ and $y$ and you get the same result.